# Different logo page wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, header

I trying to display a different logo for a page in a wordpress site.

I have the default Logo theme, and i want to insert a different logo for a page.

here is the code that manage the logo display in the theme file:

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url() ?>/" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ) ?>" class="logo <?php if ( empty( $logo ) || $logo_type === 'site-title' ) echo 'text-logo' //xss ok ?>" style="min-width:<?php echo $logo_size['width'] / 2 // xss ok ?>px"><?php
    if ( $logo && $logo_type === 'image' ):
    ?>

        <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $logo )  ?>  " alt="<?php bloginfo( 'name' )?>" class="normal-logo" height="<?php if ( ! empty( $logo_size['height'] ) ) echo $logo_size['height']/2 // xss ok ?>" style="<?php echo esc_attr( $logo_style ) ?>"/>

    <?php
    else:
        bloginfo( 'name' );
    endif;

    ?
```

I want to insert a condtional tags function after the **img src=** like this:

```
else if(is_page('Name-Page')){
echo '<img src="images/logo-for-page.png" />';
}
```

I try to insert the funcion directly after the img src but t doesn't work.
Any idea? thank you

Comment: use if condition as @wr1t3r said .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="<?php echo ( is_page('Name-Page') ? "images/logo-for-page.png" : esc_url( $logo ) ) ?>" ....
```